# How to use iOS 10.3 devices with Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: xcode8, ios10.3

This iPad mini 2 (Model A1490) is running iOS 10.3 (14E277), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

my xcode version 8.2.1
my Device ios version 10.2

Comment: This is ridiculous - Apple says i don't even have an update for Xcode in the app store.

Comment: Xcode is available but required Sierra (10.12). I need to a trick for work with osx 10.11, xcode 8.2.1 and ios 10.3

Comment: need a fix for that, too! i am using osx 10.11 and xcode 8.2.1, too

Comment: developing for apple products is the worst experience ever. after every update in iOS my development env is stuck and i have to do this and that to do even simple debugging on my own iphone

Comment: @Adeem But the colors are much nicer than in Visual Studio.

Comment: iPhone Developer for nearly 6 years now - but Ive got to say this is one of the very crappest things.  Im constantly unsure whether I can update my phone and whether or not it will break XCode.  Sort it out Apple.

Comment: @LukeSmith agreed. I been developing for 8 yrs now and Apple are so stupid right now I can't even begin to say how much i hate them.

Comment: @Adeem and the download size 4.5 GB. Awesome.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In order to run your app on 10.3 device with Xcode 8.2.1 you'll need a new Developer Disk Image for 10.3.

You can follow this user's guide [here](https://gist.github.com/steipete/d9b44d8e9f341e81414e86d7ff8fb62d#gistcomment-2041802) that seems is working for me too. Use at your own risk.

Steps:

1.Download Zip file and extract.

2.Click on "Finder" in MAC OS

3.Click on "Go to Folder"

4.Paste 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport . Otherwise go to Applications > Right Click on Xcode > Show Package Contents and follow the directories above.

5.You'll notice that your versions ends at 10.2. So you need the new 10.3. Paste downloaded folder.

6.Reboot Device + Xcode + Mac

Comment: Only needed to disconnect & reconnect device restart Xcode. Also, you'll need to wait for Xcode to process the symbol files but this solution works :)

Comment: It is possible to [avoid the Dropbox download and download from Apple instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43696751/385513).

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: uuh - i strongly not recommend to download xcode from unknown source. i remember there was a infection vector by installing xcode from download servers in china. all apps build with this xocde got infected

Comment: This has saved me twice now.

Answer (score 85):

You can avoid both the [update to Xcode 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43102666/385513) (which works only with macOS Sierra) and the [Dropbox download from a random link on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43145840/385513), as suggested in other answers. To work with iOS 10.3 in Xcode 8.2.1, follow these steps:

- Exit Xcode 8.2.1
- Download `Xcode8.3.3.xip` from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.3.3/Xcode8.3.3.xip) (requires sign-in)
- Unzip `~/Downloads/Xcode8.3.3.xip` (in Finder, double-click)
- Copy folder `10.3.1 (14E8301)` from `~/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` (in Finder, right click on `Xcode.app` and 'Show Package Contents')
- Remove `~/Downloads/Xcode8.3.3.xip` and `~/Downloads/Xcode.app`
- Start Xcode 8.2.1. Done.

Comment: Nice hack! Works without upgrading to macOS Sierra.

Comment: In Xcode 8.2, iOS 10.3 won't appear as an option in the base SDK nor in the iOS Deployment Target, but you can still deploy the app to your iOS 10.3 device without problem.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. If you want to download stuff from Apple and not from an unknown developer and also to not have to upgrade your Mac to Sierra then use this solution.

Comment: This worked great! I got the app to build but initially it wouldn't run on the device. Xcode complained in the console that `dyld` would not load `libswiftAVFoundation.dylib` as no suitable image was found and the only available one had an invalid code signature... So I did a `Product -> Clean` action (CMD-Shift-K) and rebuilt the app and that solved it.

Comment: Thanx a lot. you saved my day. I was hitting my head around and did not have any idea that this would work. (Y)

Comment: For some reason Finder gets stuck at verifying the xip. Any ideas?

Comment: I had to restart macOS.

Comment: @Pier you must have patience, it takes a while, xip unpacks from 4gb to 10gb and then verifies all files.

Comment: @frank Seifert - Do you have a new trick now that iOS 11.0.2 is out?  Apparently my device updated to it last night and now I'm stuck...

Comment: this is still working to run on iOS 12 using Xcode 9, just that I didnt copy the whole  DeviceSupport folder, only the 12.0 folder, which I think is better

Answer (score 12):

Just solved it. Get new Xcode here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12

Comment: This should be the correct answer, and not downvoted... All you need to do is manually search "xcode" on the App store and download it. It won't show up on your dock as an available download depending on how you first installed it.

Comment: Thanks, @Joe. No idea why no one liked the answer - this was an easy fix.

Comment: fixed it for me!

Comment: Note that this requires Mac OS 10.12 (Sierra). If you try to install on Mac OS 10.11, the Mac App Store doesn't show an error, it just shows an endless activity indicator.

Comment: Good point @arlomedia - Every time you update Xcode, OSX, or iOS, they ALL need to be the most current, or you will get the same error that was addressed in this question. The easiest way to avoid this is to ALWAYS make sure that, if you update one of the three, you make sure to update the other two...or at least make sure all three are THE MOST CURRENT.

Comment: The versions aren't always coupled that tightly -- for example, I didn't have to update my Mac to develop on iOS 10.1 or 10.2 devices, and I'm still developing on iOS 8 devices with Xcode 8.2 -- but sometimes they are, which can bite you if you're not prepared to update your whole Mac system.

Comment: I was bit by this, and was unprepared to buy a new Mac to run Sierra officially. Which itself seems like an odd problem to have, but some of us are broke, yo. It's a crude hack or nothing for me for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Upgrading xcode is not the "correct" answer @joe, but it is "an" answer. The question specifically asks for how to deploy to ios 10.3 WITH his current version of XCode, which jejix answered directly.

Answer (score 3):

According to the message it feedbacks to you, I believe your device iOS version is 10.3. And you have to update your Xcode to 8.3 since it provides the necessary SDKs for iOS 10.3 ([see more detail from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html)).

I think what you can do is:

1. Double check your device iOS version
2. If it is iOS 10.3, update your Xcode from App Store (Notice that it requires your Mac running macOS 10.12 or later). Or if you have to test your project on iOS 10.2, just find a way to downgrade it ([Downgrade iOS 10.3 to the previous iOS version](https://www.imobie.com/support/downgrade-from-ios-10-to-ios-9.htm)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had to go through downgrade option using https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201274 having MacBook from beginning of 2009 which is not supported by macOS Sierra.

Comment: But no, it haven't restored previous iOS version. Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue, for me the fix was to keep running the app from xcode...eventually it just booted up on my phone and the error went away.

Hopefully this helps someone!