# How can i use IOS10.3.1 devices on my Xcode 8.3 without updating MacOs or Updating Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode8, ios10.3

I bought new iphone 6 running iOS 10.3.1 (14E304), and while connecting with Xcode and running my code on this device and its saying this device is not supporting by this xcode.

Can anyone suggest me how can i run my iOS device(10.3.1) with Xcode (8.2.1)

Appreciate all answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How using iOS 10.3 devices with Xcode 8.2.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099863/how-using-ios-10-3-devices-with-xcode-8-2-1)

Comment: Hey @Kalpesh - I am also facing same issues, when you find solution let me know.

Comment: You'll need 10.3.1 Developer Disk Image file. As shallowThought mentioned, follow this thread and check what suggested on the right answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43145840/2018028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I develop with Unity for iOS and have the same problem. Looks like you need to install macOS Sierra ( 10.12 or later ) to install a newer XCode ( 8.3+ ) version.