# Getting Xcode 8.3.0 to compile to ios 10.3.1 on OSX 10.11.6

Tags: ios, xcode

How do I go about doing this without updating to Seirra? Apple drives me nuts with this constant yak shaving.

Comment: For context, because the Apple side of things isn't explicit, in case it helps somebody get to an answer: Apple states that 8.3.x requires 10.12. The author is asking whether they can use it on 10.11.

Comment: You can use Xcode 8.2.x under OSX 10.11.x: [How using iOS 10.3 devices with Xcode 8.2.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099863/how-using-ios-10-3-devices-with-xcode-8-2-1)

Comment: I'll add to that clarification. I just started a roll of projects, and XCode / iOS dev isn't one of my primary utilities, but I wanted to use it for an experiment. I am hesitant to update because I find the OSX updates tend to muck up my other dev environments. :-/

Comment: 10.12 is the first version since 10.8 to drop support for some Macs, mostly those from around 2009 and earlier; I therefore think there'll be some people asking the question regardless of how well their other environments survive OS updates.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/michalzelinka/Xcode83onElCapitan is a patch that provides "a pretty nasty and a bit complicated way how to launch and use Xcode 8.3+ on OS X El Capitan" which will result in "Xcode more or less working", though the author advises that "[i]t's not recommended to use such bumped version of Xcode neither to upload builds to the App Store nor to use it as your primary Xcode installation".

The patch does this by providing a reimplementation of those parts of 10.12 that Xcode relies on. Given that it was last updated 22 days ago, I'd dare imagine that it has been updated for the latest Xcode, 8.3.2.