# Could not locate device support files

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I want to run my IOS application on iphone but I am getting below mentioned error.

"This iPhone 6 is running iOS 10.3.2 (14F89), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode."

[image: Screenshot]

How to fix it.

Comment: What xcode version ur using.?

Comment: xcode version is 8

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5nII3I5riR2SGZZLWExVjZJVmc/view Download this file, Extract and rename it to  **iOS 10.3.2 (14F89)**. Copy it this directory path `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`. Quit and reopen ur xcode reconnect ur device and run

Answer (score 2):

Your version of xCode does not support iOS 10.3.2.

Just check, your deploy target contains iOS 10.3 or not. If not, you should use another version of xCode.

[image]

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: @Ragini, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade your Xcode to v8.3 in order to install your build on iOS 10.3.

If you wish to use the Xcode 8.2 in order to run a build on iOS 10.3 then check this thread: [How to use iOS 10.3 devices with Xcode 8.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099863/how-to-use-ios-10-3-devices-with-xcode-8-2-1/43102666#43102666)

Answer (score 0):

Your Xcode version doesnot support devices above 10.3 iOS version. The device which you connected is above 10.3. One solution is to download the respective developer disk image from somewhere and save it to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport and restart Xcode. Second solution is to update your Xcode.

Answer (score -1):

Just create .ipa file and run using itunes, otherwise you need to update your xcode to newer version